# How to print strings in ViewPart in RCP?

Tags: eclipse, view, printing, rcp

Do I need some controls to hold the strings? Or is there a way to print the strings just like the eclipse itself using 'System.out.println'?

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add controls to the part for anything you want to show.

A simple control just to show a list:

```java
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

  parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  List list = new List(parent, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);

  list.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

  ...

  list.add("text");
```

`System.out.println` output will print on the Eclipse console when you debug your RCP but will be lost in the deployed application (unless you open the Java console).